# clustered dataframe from json file

Tags: python, json

I abstracted news data from the guardian and store it in a json file, however, I get the [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6k21.png) with the response data while I want the [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAGkF.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you include some code so we can better understand what you've done so far?

Comment: Don't post data or code as images. Post relevant code with your question, along with a clear indication of the expected result and the actual result. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask